# Forms inside td html

Tags: javascript, php, html

My html code is:

```
<table><tr><td  onclick="submit_form_patient();")>
<form name="select_patient" method="POST" action="./select_bed.php">
<input name="raw_data" type="hidden" value="27" />27</form>
</td></tr>
<tr><td  onclick="submit_form_patient();")>
<form name="select_patient" method="POST" action="./select_bed.php">
<input name="raw_data" type="hidden" value="49" />49</form></td></tr>
```

My Java script is:

```
<script>
function submit_form_patient()
{
    document.forms["select_patient"].submit();
}
</script>
```

My form gets submitted but if I use $_POST to retrieve the values I get 27 all the time namely the first value I never get the other values.

Comment: thats because its always the fist form being submitted with the name select_patient

Comment: use "this" in submit_form_patient to get expected form submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours forms have same name. You need to name them differently.

And modify js code:

```
<script>
    function submit_form_patient(formName)
    {
        document.forms[formName].submit();
    }
    </script>
```

And html code need to be like this

```
        <table>
<tr>
<td  onclick="submit_form_patient('select_patient');")>
    <form name="select_patient" method="POST" action="./select_bed.php">
    <input name="raw_data" type="hidden" value="27" />27</form>
</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
<td  onclick="submit_form_patient('select_patient2');")>
    <form name="select_patient2" method="POST" action="./select_bed.php">
    <input name="raw_data" type="hidden" value="49" />49</form>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `name` of the `form`s is the same. I don't know whether the standard handles this, but browsers pick the first matching item. So it's always going to be the first.

Create only *one* form, and based on the click POST the right value.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `document.forms["select_patient"].submit();`, JS will find first form/element with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
function submit_form_patient()
{
    document.getElementsByName("select_patient")[0].submit();
    document.getElementsByName("select_patient")[1].submit();
}
</script>
```

you can also create a for block to be more consistent.